# tcolorbox: using self defined colors

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I have a self defined color:

```
\definecolor{my-blue}{cmyk}{0.80, 0.13, 0.14, 0.04, 1.00}
```

I want to use it for a `tcolorbox` environment:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback = \color{my-blue}]
stuff
\end{tcolorbox}
```

however I am just getting mostly unnamed errors (literally ''!'') and the occasional color protected...

Comment: As far as I know, `cmyk` wants *four* numbers, not five.

Comment: A fifth number can specify the alpha

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value of the `colback` option is the name of the color, not the `\color` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{my-blue}{cmyk}{0.80, 0.13, 0.14, 0.04, 1.00}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback = my-blue]
stuff
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tired just using my-blue but it gave errors, hence trying \color{my-blue}